# Angular on PhoneGap, ngView changes same page multiple times generating $digest error

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build, ngroute, ng-view

I am trying to port a web app to mobile using Cordova PhoneGap. It works more or less as expected, except for the `ngView` directive.

[OLD PROBLEM]

When I change page, the new page overlays on the old one, mixing their elements. I solved this with an asynchronous bootstrap of Angular, after the deviceReady event.

[UNSOLVED PROBLEM]

I can see on Xcode also a huge use of memory during run-time. At the *home page* I see about 90MB of use. If I go to the *user page* (much more heavy), memory consumption is about 200MB. If I come back to the *home page*, memory increases instead of coming back to 90MB.
I noticed that when I open a new page, its controller is initialized multiple times generating the `$digest` loop error. In fact when I go to the home page, the log writes *'PAGE OPENED!!'* 10 times

I don't have pending `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. 
I guess that when a scope is destroyed, also its controller does.

This is how I use ngview:

index.html

```
<body ng-cloak class="ng-cloak" style="overflow-y: auto;">
     <div ng-view></div>
    ...
</body>
```

app.modules.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [...])

  .config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider   
           .when('/home',{
                  templateUrl: 'app/home.html',
                })      
           .when('/user',{
                  templateUrl: 'app/user/profile.html',
                });                                                         
})
```

home.html

```
<div id='home_page' ng-controller="homePageController as ctrl"
     ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+{{ctrl.image}}+')'}">

        <div>
            this is the home page
        </div>   
</div>
```

homePageController.js

```
.controller('homePageController', [function($scope)
{
 self.image="/img/img.png";
 console.log('PAGE OPENED!!');

 this.pageClosed = function()
    { $scope.$destroy(); }
}]);
```

It works well on the browser, I can't understand why I can't smoothly change pages in the app.

Thank you

Comment: there isn't enough code here to help diagnose the issue.  without seeing exactly how your markup and your route service is declared, it's not possible to know if this is an issue with your declarations or an issue with the routeProvider, but the routeProvider being broken is highly doubtful.

Comment: I added some code, but it's very standard. I really don't know how to help you to help me.

Comment: You're not setting any controller for those views, is that correct? You should assign a controller to each 'when' statement along with each 'templateUrl'. It can't be seen where/how you're loading your controllers.

Comment: I set the controllers in each template. I'm going to update the code

Comment: I have updated my question, with some news. Thank you